# How can I use Selenium 'Until' function without throwing an Exception?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a test script using selenium that might interact with an element but if the element is not there it will not. I need to add that the element might take some time to appear. The issue is that if I use FindElement I get an exception. If I use FindElements it take too long. So, I tried to used "until" function which work well to wait until the element to appear... but if it doesn't appear it throws an exception I want to avoid that.

I know I can use a try catch.But, is there any  better way to do this?
I curently have this:

```
IWebElement button;
try{
    string x = "search query";
    button = this.WaitDriver.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(x)));
}catch{
    button = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test for existence without a `try-catch` then you would have to use `.FindElements()`. It shouldn't take any longer than `.FindElement()` using the same wait but the wait will time out if the element doesn't exist... which is a pain. One way to get around this is to do something like the below. It's basically what you had with a few tweaks.

```
public bool ElementExists(By locator)
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(locator));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) when (e is NoSuchElementException || e is WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I prefer checking for existence rather returning a `null` because then you have to check for `null` also. By putting this in a function, you can call it whenever and your tests stay cleaner. You would use it like

```
By locator = By.Id("someId");
if (ElementExists(locator))
{
    IWebElement e = driver.FindElement(locator);
    // do something with e
}
```

Comment: OP clearly mentioned _I can use a try catch.But, is there any better way to do this?_ but your answer contains a **try catch{}** in the form of a additional wrapper. Did you read the question actually?

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes, I did. Did read my answer? I started off by explaining that it can be done without a `try-catch` as long as you don't need a wait. Once you need a wait, you have to use a `try-catch`. That part is only 4 sentences...

Comment: You can use findElements for searching the WebElements and store the result in an arrayList. If the size of the arraylist is less than 1, we get to know that the element is not there.

Comment: @Neha Are you talking to me or DebanjanB? I am aware... that's in my answer.

Comment: At the end I gave up and did something like this